# How to spy on a function that is expected to be asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jasmine

I have this function that I expect to be invoked after 5s of invoking the jasmine test script.

I tried the traditional way described in the jasmine docs:

```
describe("Tests:", function(){
  it("Expects slowFunction() will be called", function(){
    var slowFunctionSpy = spyOn(window, 'slowFunction').andCallThrough();
    init();
    waitsFor(function() {      
      expect(slowFunctionSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();      
    }, "Call Not Answered by Remote End.", 10000);
  });    
});
```

the `init()` function fires a chain of events, that is it inoves a function which ultimately brings it to `slowFunction()` being invoked.
I have left out the run() method because I think if the `waitsFor()` gets the `expect()` to be `true` the test should pass right?

I have also tried [jasmine.async](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/08/18/jasmine-async-making-asynchronous-testing-with-jasmine-suck-less/) but the test still fails.

```
describe("Tests:", function(){

  var foo=false;
  var async = new AsyncSpec(this);

  async.beforeEach(function(done){
    setTimeout(function(done){
      foo = true;
      init();
      done();
    }, 10000);    
  });

  it("Expects slowFunction() will be called", function(){
    var slowFunctionSpy = spyOn(window, 'slowFunction').andCallThrough();
    expect(slowFunctionSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();      
    });
});
```

Probably theres something I do not clearly understand about. Some help in clearing out my ideas please?

**UPDATE:** `slowFunction()` is a custom event and based on my google search outcome, I think spyOn() doesnt work for events. So new question:

**How to spy on a custom event in Jasmine?**

Comment: Is the function you want to test passed on setTimeout?

Comment: @AndreasKöberle No no. On `init()` a `login()` function is called. And following that there are a set of events that ultimately lead to this function. So when I run this test I am sure that this method is invoked. Just that the tests are failing for this.

Comment: It would help if show us the function you wanna test.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle Its part of the code. http://pastebin.com/ZwQnfDux
So when I call login() from init(), the event onLogin() occurs. I have a successful test for spying on onLogin(). So when onLogin() occurs, it makes a call and consequently, the call is answered on the other end under 5s. So I want to test for onCallAnswered().

Comment: why leaving out the `runs()` block? async operations are supposed to be wrapped in such blocks.